# How to read Dictionary from FireBase Database in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, dictionary, unity-game-engine

[image]

```
public void AddDatabase(User user)
{

    //User user = new User("pç", 2);
    Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    result["score"] = user.score;
    result["username"] = user.username;
    reference.Child("datas").Child(user.username).SetValueAsync(result);

}



public void GetDatabase()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("datas").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            // Handle the error...
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

            ArrayList childs = new ArrayList();
            //Dictionary<string, object> xyz = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (var item in snapshot.Children)
            {
                childs.Add(item.Value);

                //xyz.Add("dat", item.Value);
            }

            // this does not work I can't see values and keys in the console
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in childs)
            {   
                Debug.Log(item.Key);
                Debug.Log(item.Value);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I write datas into firebase with AddDatabase and I want to read every Score and Username one by one in order with GetDatabase so I can put them Leaderboard  but I can't how can I do that and I already checked firebase database docs.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the data returned in `GetValueAsync`, `DataSnapshot` may have a `Dictionary<string, object>` in it already:

```
public void GetDatabase()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("datas").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            // Handle the error...
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            var dictionary = snapshot.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;
            if (dictionary != null) {
                // dictionary stuff here
            }
        }
    });
}
```

From [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_data_snapshot_1a45e32265ebf6ad5ee66848b425e9a934):

> Value returns the data contained in this snapshot as native types. The possible types returned are:
>
> - bool
> - string
> - long
> - double
> - IDictionary{string, object}
> - List{object} This list is recursive; the possible types for object in the above list is given by the same list. These types correspond to the types available in JSON.

Now a quick note: the Unity SDK does guess at whether the `Value` should be a `List` or a `Dictionary` if it has children. The general rule is:
It's a List if the elements are sequential and roughly 50% of the keys in the range are filled (ex: 0="hi", 1="I'm", 3="a", 4="list" is a list even though it's missing 2). Otherwise it will try to make a Dictionary. If you are dealing with integer keys, you may want to have mirrored logic for dealing with a List or Dictionary just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `snapshot.Children` and what is the type of its contents? If the contents is not of type `KeyValuePair<string, object>` then the second foreach loop won't work properly (I am not familiar enough with non-generic collections to say what would actually happen).

I strongly recommend using types from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, such as `List<T>`, rather than non-generic collections like `ArrayList`. This will make it easier to see what your code is doing. In addition to being easier to work with, they also have better performance because they don't require casting.

Comment: snapshot.Children gives every value as "basaramadik", "basaramiyomabi" but when I want to read their values for example inside "basaramadik" it returns system.collections.generic.dictionary 2 and I must read them into dictionary but I can't

Comment: Based on the firebase documentation, snapshot.Children is an IEnumerable<DataSnapshot>. You are going to need to read the DataSnapshot.Value property of either snapshot itself or of the DataSnapshots inside snapshot.Children.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the two examples:

- [How to use Firebase Database in Unity (REST API)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fz0Sl4tW5O0)
- [Retrieving Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data)

Comment: Questions to get more info about the problem should be posted as comments to the original question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: @fernandospr At that time my reputation was too low to comment. But now I have the opportunity and I use it.